# Alternatives to subclassing to handle UI vs behavior concerns in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, design-patterns

I've been wrestling with several design options for an app rewrite and can't seem to get going because I can't come up with a design I like. Most of my concerns stem from subclassing issues. Basically, I have some aspects that I want to be reused among multiple classes:

- User interface "look and feel"
- User interface behaviors (dialogs, activity indicators, navigation)
- Network interface (like Three20's `ModelViewController`, something like a `load`, `more`, and so forth)
- State-driven behaviors (changes in reachability, login status, notifications, etc)

Since Obj-C does not support multiple inheritance I cannot do something like `MyViewController : StandardUILookNFeelViewController, NetworkEnabledViewController`. I know that I can use protocols in the same way that you use interfaces in Java, but I do not know whether I should subclass the look and feel, the network behaviors, the state-driven behaviors, or try to throw it all in one class.

In your experience, do you use your `BaseViewController` to handle look and feel, do you use it to handle network stuff, do you use it to handle behaviors? Do you throw all of these into one class? Do you have a large class hierarchy like `three20`'s, or is there a more clever solution I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

People tend to lump functionality into view controllers because "it's convenient." But a single class that handles multiple responsibilities, by definition, violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

This is important for readability, maintainability, and testability. And if you want reuse, it's essential.

I recommend reading up on:

- [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) (not a Three20 class, but a design principle)
- [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)
- [Single Responsibility Principle](https://qualitycoding.org/single-responsibility-principle/)